# How to resolve App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am facing below unwanted console messages while running my app by using `Xcode 7 beta` with `iOS 9`. Please help me how to resolve below one.

Console Message:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transport Security has Blocked a cleartext HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: Thats Not working for me!

Comment: You're doing something wrong, In fact it didn't work for me the first time, but I tried ```<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>``` and it worked

Comment: oh ok. I will try. thank you!